# How to create a Priority queue schedule in Autosys?

Tags: batch-processing, schedule, informatica, autosys

Technologies available: Autosys, Informatica, Unix scripting, Database (available via informatica)

How our batch currently works is with filewatchers looking for a file called "control.txt" which gets deleted when a feed starts processing. It gets recreated once completed which allows all "control" autosys jobs waiting, to have one pick up the control file and begin processing data feeds one by one.

However, the system has grown large, and some feeds have become more important than others, and we're looking at ways to improve our scheduler to prioritize feeds over others.

With the current design, of one a file deciding when the next feed runs, it can't be done, and I haven't been able to come up with a simple solution to make it happen.

Example:

```
1. Feed A is processing
2. Feed B, Feed C, Feed X, Feed F come in while Feed A is processing
3. Need to ensure that Feed B is processed next, even though C, X, F are ready. 
4. C, X, F have a lower priority than A and B, but have the same priority and can process in any order
```

Comment: You can also rename the control.txt file with respect to the feeds

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question. One thing that I can think of is to have an extra Autosys job with a shell script that copies the file in certain order. Like:

- Create input folder e.g. StageFolder
- Let's call your current Autosys input folder "the InputFolder"
- Have Autosys monitor it and for any file run a OrderedFileCopyScript.sh, every minute
- OrderedFileCopyScript.sh should copy one file from StageFolder to InputFolder in desired order only if InputFolder is empty

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: This is a start, problem is changing the file names and location would create a large amount of extra work that would deem the project not feasible.However, I know you couldn't have known that.

Comment: Well... I'm just throwing up some ideas within the constraints given :) However: no file name changes would be needed, just additional folder.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's why I was trying to say. I'm very appreciative for any help. I just wasn't being detailed enough. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I oppose use of Autosys for this requirement ! Wrong tool !

I don't know all the details but considering an application with the usual reference tables.

In this case you should make use of feed reference table to include relative priorities.

I would suggest to create(or reuse) a table to loaded by the successor job of the file watcher.

**1)** Table to contain the unprocessed file with the corresponding priority and then use this table to process the files based on the priority.

**2)** Remove/archive the entries once done.

**3)** Have another job of this and run like a daemon with start_times/run_window.

This gives the flexibility to deal with change in priorities and keeps overall design simple.

This gives